# Does QGIS support topological editing of lines?

Tags: qgis, editing, topology

Does QGIS support topological editing of shared vertices between two or more lines? When in editing mode, if I select a vertex at an intersection, it seems that sometimes it will move all lines connected to that vertex, and sometimes not.

I am using QGIS 2.6 and have Enable topological editing turned on in the Snapping options. These lines are all within the same layer.

Comment: Thanks, have tested later versions and don't experience the same issue. Submit that as an answer if you like.

Comment: QGIS 2.6 it is old version and may have some issues. If it's possible update QGIS version to newest.

Answer (score 2):

This is an option (turned on or off) in QGIS. The settings for the latest QGIS 3 are described in this question/answer: [How can I enable topological editing in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302965/how-can-i-enable-topological-editing-in-qgis-3)